# Run a .net project on a system with IIS but no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2012

I have a MVC 5 web application that is working fine. But **due to internal security reasons and restrictions of my organization, I cannot host it** as a website. My current requirement is to **make this app run on a particular computer that has IIS installed on it but no Visual Studio**.

My application makes use of **MS-SQL database, Entity Framework, C# razors and all other .NET dependencies** that are usual in a MVC app, and my **target framework is 4.5.1** .

**What I Found** : I googled a lot, what I got is to create a **Virtual Directory** using the **inetmgr** and create the application under that directory. But since already the application is created I cannot go for this fix.

Please help me out by providing some links to refer to or steps to solve this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is to either:

- Use Visual Studio to publish the website directly onto the machine which is hosting the IIS application, as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Use Visual Studio an publish the application to a folder location on your machine and then use remote desktop or some other method to move the published DLL's to the virtual directory of the application.

Essentially both of them do the same thing, but sometimes due to security reasons, option 2 is easier to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry if I ask a silly question as I am new to this. Does 'Deploying' not mean 'Publishing' in some way? I mean I cannot publish it anywhere and No one should be able to access this application except only the owner of the target system. I want some sort of a way to run the application in the same way how I do it on my machine with IIS and VS, so that only I have access to the DB. Same way I want only the owner of the target system to have access to the db and no one else. However, the only catch is that there is no VS on the target system.

Comment: @AkashdeepBhattacharya: If I am understanding you correctly, you could still publish the site on your machine and then give it to the owner of the system to deploy it on his end.